# How on button click show another layout (xml) with their class?

Tags: android

I have MainActivity extends Activity which is showed by default when I open app and layout (xml) is main_activity.xml. What I want is on button click show another layout with their class, for example InfoView. How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest you use `Fragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add FrameLayout in you main_activity.xml as a container for the new View with id for example id="@id+/main_activity_container"

Then in your method

```
public void onClick(View view){
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)findVideById(R.id.main_activity_container);
    container.removeAllViews();
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View yourNewView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newView, container,false);
    container.addView(container);
}
```

Fragment implemantation:

```
public void onClick(View view){
    Fragment fragmentWithYourNewView = initFragment();

    FragmentManager frMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction frTr = frMan.beginTransaction();
    frTr.add(R.id.main_activity_container,fragmentWithYourNewView);
    frTr.commit();
}
```

In this case if user press back button it returns in previus state.

Comment: and how then back to main_activity layout again?

Comment: You can`t. But you can manage Views in your containerView. In this case there is now internal backStack mechanism. But FragmentManager has it.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use an intent to switch between Activities. Each Class related with a Layout, is called Activity (general talking).

Read more here. It's so easy to use!

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

If you want to keep the same Activity, you can use a Fragment (which is a little bit harder for a starter or just use `this.setContentView(R.layout.anyotherlayout)`to change the layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
boolean isSecondLayout;

public void onClick(View view){
    if (!isSecondLayout) {
        MainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.InfoView);
        isSecondLayout = true;
    } else {
        MainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        isSecondLayout = false;
    }
}
```